# How to get the first audio channel from a video with ffmpeg-python?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I would like to get the very first audio channel from a video using ffmpeg-python.

I tried with this:

```
  out, _ = (
        ffmpeg
            .input(filename)
            .output('pipe:', loglevel=0, format='s16le', acodec='pcm_s16le', ac=1, ar='8k')
            .run(capture_stdout=True)
    )
    """ extract audio signal """
    self.signal = (
        np
            .frombuffer(out, np.int16)  
    )
```

but I am not sure whether this is correct.

I had a look here, but I could not find a solution: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation

Any suggestion? Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried @rotem solution and it seems to work. However, I have another issue which seems related to the -ac flag. For some videos, the numpy output has the right length (i.e., it matches the original audio length). For others, I get a wrong one. However, if  I set -ac to 2 for these videos, I get the correct signal length. Do you know why is this happening?

This is the metadata of the video (duration: 2 minutes and 11 seconds) which outputs the correct numpy array size with setting -ac to 2

{'streams': [{'index': 0, 'codec_name': 'h264', 'codec_long_name': 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10', 'profile': 'High', 'codec_type': 'video', 'codec_tag_string': 'avc1', 'codec_tag': '0x31637661', 'width': 1920, 'height': 1080, 'coded_width': 1920, 'coded_height': 1080, 'closed_captions': 0, 'film_grain': 0, 'has_b_frames': 0, 'pix_fmt': 'yuv420p', 'level': 40, 'color_range': 'tv', 'color_space': 'bt709', 'color_transfer': 'bt709', 'color_primaries': 'bt709', 'chroma_location': 'left', 'field_order': 'progressive', 'refs': 1, 'is_avc': 'true', 'nal_length_size': '4', 'id': '0x1', 'r_frame_rate': '30/1', 'avg_frame_rate': '176805000/5894849', 'time_base': '1/90000', 'start_pts': 0, 'start_time': '0.000000', 'duration_ts': 11789698, 'duration': '130.996644', 'bit_rate': '16999840', 'bits_per_raw_sample': '8', 'nb_frames': '3929', 'extradata_size': 34, 'disposition': {'default': 1, 'dub': 0, 'original': 0, 'comment': 0, 'lyrics': 0, 'karaoke': 0, 'forced': 0, 'hearing_impaired': 0, 'visual_impaired': 0, 'clean_effects': 0, 'attached_pic': 0, 'timed_thumbnails': 0, 'captions': 0, 'descriptions': 0, 'metadata': 0, 'dependent': 0, 'still_image': 0}, 'tags': {'creation_time': '2022-05-30T15:00:39.000000Z', 'language': 'eng', 'handler_name': 'VideoHandle', 'vendor_id': '[0][0][0][0]'}}, {'index': 1, 'codec_name': 'aac', 'codec_long_name': 'AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)', 'profile': 'LC', 'codec_type': 'audio', 'codec_tag_string': 'mp4a', 'codec_tag': '0x6134706d', 'sample_fmt': 'fltp', 'sample_rate': '48000', 'channels': 2, 'channel_layout': 'stereo', 'bits_per_sample': 0, 'id': '0x2', 'r_frame_rate': '0/0', 'avg_frame_rate': '0/0', 'time_base': '1/48000', 'start_pts': 696, 'start_time': '0.014500', 'duration_ts': 6285214, 'duration': '130.941958', 'bit_rate': '256004', 'nb_frames': '6138', 'extradata_size': 2, 'disposition': {'default': 1, 'dub': 0, 'original': 0, 'comment': 0, 'lyrics': 0, 'karaoke': 0, 'forced': 0, 'hearing_impaired': 0, 'visual_impaired': 0, 'clean_effects': 0, 'attached_pic': 0, 'timed_thumbnails': 0, 'captions': 0, 'descriptions': 0, 'metadata': 0, 'dependent': 0, 'still_image': 0}, 'tags': {'creation_time': '2022-05-30T15:00:39.000000Z', 'language': 'eng', 'handler_name': 'SoundHandle', 'vendor_id': '[0][0][0][0]'}}], 'format': {'filename': 'videos4/test_01.mp4', 'nb_streams': 2, 'nb_programs': 0, 'format_name': 'mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2', 'format_long_name': 'QuickTime / MOV', 'start_time': '0.000000', 'duration': '130.996600', 'size': '282621379', 'bit_rate': '17259768', 'probe_score': 100, 'tags': {'major_brand': 'mp42', 'minor_version': '0', 'compatible_brands': 'isommp42', 'creation_time': '2022-05-30T15:00:39.000000Z', 'com.android.version': '12', 'com.android.capture.fps': '30.000000'}}}.

This is instead, the metadata of the video (duration 5 minutes) which gives the right result length with setting -ac to 1:

{'streams': [{'index': 0, 'codec_name': 'h264', 'codec_long_name': 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10', 'profile': 'High', 'codec_type': 'video', 'codec_tag_string': 'avc1', 'codec_tag': '0x31637661', 'width': 1920, 'height': 1080, 'coded_width': 1920, 'coded_height': 1080, 'closed_captions': 0, 'film_grain': 0, 'has_b_frames': 0, 'sample_aspect_ratio': '1:1', 'display_aspect_ratio': '16:9', 'pix_fmt': 'yuv420p', 'level': 40, 'field_order': 'progressive', 'refs': 1, 'is_avc': 'true', 'nal_length_size': '4', 'id': '0x1', 'r_frame_rate': '30/1', 'avg_frame_rate': '33862500/1128779', 'time_base': '1/90000', 'start_pts': 0, 'start_time': '0.000000', 'duration_ts': 27090696, 'duration': '301.007733', 'bit_rate': '16999542', 'bits_per_raw_sample': '8', 'nb_frames': '9030', 'extradata_size': 26, 'disposition': {'default': 1, 'dub': 0, 'original': 0, 'comment': 0, 'lyrics': 0, 'karaoke': 0, 'forced': 0, 'hearing_impaired': 0, 'visual_impaired': 0, 'clean_effects': 0, 'attached_pic': 0, 'timed_thumbnails': 0, 'captions': 0, 'descriptions': 0, 'metadata': 0, 'dependent': 0, 'still_image': 0}, 'tags': {'language': 'und', 'handler_name': 'VideoHandler', 'vendor_id': '[0][0][0][0]'}, 'side_data_list': [{'side_data_type': 'Display Matrix', 'displaymatrix': '\n00000000:            0       65536           0\n00000001:       -65536           0           0\n00000002:            0           0  1073741824\n', 'rotation': -90}]}, {'index': 1, 'codec_name': 'aac', 'codec_long_name': 'AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)', 'profile': 'LC', 'codec_type': 'audio', 'codec_tag_string': 'mp4a', 'codec_tag': '0x6134706d', 'sample_fmt': 'fltp', 'sample_rate': '48000', 'channels': 2, 'channel_layout': 'stereo', 'bits_per_sample': 0, 'id': '0x2', 'r_frame_rate': '0/0', 'avg_frame_rate': '0/0', 'time_base': '1/48000', 'start_pts': 0, 'start_time': '0.000000', 'duration_ts': 14448640, 'duration': '301.013333', 'bit_rate': '256000', 'nb_frames': '14110', 'extradata_size': 2, 'disposition': {'default': 1, 'dub': 0, 'original': 0, 'comment': 0, 'lyrics': 0, 'karaoke': 0, 'forced': 0, 'hearing_impaired': 0, 'visual_impaired': 0, 'clean_effects': 0, 'attached_pic': 0, 'timed_thumbnails': 0, 'captions': 0, 'descriptions': 0, 'metadata': 0, 'dependent': 0, 'still_image': 0}, 'tags': {'language': 'und', 'handler_name': 'SoundHandler', 'vendor_id': '[0][0][0][0]'}}], 'format': {'filename': 'videos4/video_02.mp4', 'nb_streams': 2, 'nb_programs': 0, 'format_name': 'mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2', 'format_long_name': 'QuickTime / MOV', 'start_time': '0.000000', 'duration': '301.014000', 'size': '649577064', 'bit_rate': '17263703', 'probe_score': 100, 'tags': {'major_brand': 'isom', 'minor_version': '512', 'compatible_brands': 'isomiso2avc1mp41', 'encoder': 'Lavf58.27.103'}}}

Answer (score 0):

Use [`-map_channel` output option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

```
-map_channel [input_file_id.stream_specifier.channel_id|-1][?][:output_file_id.stream_specifier]
```

(search for "-map_channel" in the doc linked above for more details.)

To map only the first channel of the first audio stream of the first file, try

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -map_channel 0.0.0 OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest solution I could find is using [channelsplit](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-channelsplit) filter.

Example for FFmpeg CLI command:
`ffmpeg -y -vn -i stereo.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a:0]channelsplit=channel_layout=mono:channels=FC[C0]" -map "[C0]" -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 8k first_channel.wav`

The advantage is that the command works even when there is a video channel, and when there is more then one audio stream.

---

Create synthetic input files for testing (with audio and video) using FFmpeg CLI:

Build sample with stereo audio:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=100 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -map_channel 1.0.0 -map_channel 2.0.0 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -t 10 stereo.mp4`

Build sample with 6 channels audio:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=100 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=500 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=600 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=700 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=800 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=900 -map_channel 1.0.0 -map_channel 2.0.0 -map_channel 3.0.0 -map_channel 4.0.0 -map_channel 5.0.0 -map_channel 6.0.0 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 6 -t 10 six_channels.mp4`

---

FFmpeg CLI command for getting the first audio channel (for testing):

`ffmpeg -y -vn -i stereo.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a:0]channelsplit=channel_layout=mono:channels=FC[C0]" -map "[C0]" -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 8k first_channel.wav`

- `[0:a:0]` gets the first audio stream of the first input file.
- `channelsplit=channel_layout=mono:channels=FC[C0]` splits the audio channels, gets the first audio channel, and gives it a temporary name `[C0]`.
- `-map "[C0]"` maps the audio channel to the output.

---

Same command using ffmpeg-python:

```
# audio_ch0 = ffmpeg.input(filename).audio.filter('channelsplit', channel_layout='mono', channels='FC')  # Does not handle the case of multiple audio streams.

# Using ['a:0'].filter instead of .audio.filter gets the first audio stream in case there are more than one.
audio_ch0 = ffmpeg.input(filename)['a:0'].filter('channelsplit', channel_layout='mono', channels='FC')

ffmpeg.output(audio_ch0, 'first_channel.wav', acodec='pcm_s16le', ac='1', ar='8k').global_args('-hide_banner', '-report').overwrite_output().run()
```

The created log file shows that FFmpeg command is:
`ffmpeg -i stereo.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a:0]channelsplit=channel_layout=mono:channels=FC[s0]" -map "[s0]" -ac 1 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 8k first_channel.wav -hide_banner -report -y`

---

Testing:
By hearing we can verify that `first_channel.wav` is the first audio channel (100Hz sine wave).
Tested with `stereo.mp4` and `six_channels.mp4`.

---

Adjustments to your implementation:

```
import ffmpeg
import numpy as np

filename = 'stereo.mp4'

out, _ = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(filename)['a:0'].filter('channelsplit', channel_layout='mono', channels='FC')
    .output('pipe:', loglevel=0, format='s16le', acodec='pcm_s16le', ac=1, ar='8k')
    .run(capture_stdout=True)
)

""" extract audio signal """
self.signal = np.frombuffer(out, np.int16)
```

Comment: thank you very much! I edited my original question to include also the metadata of two videos that I am testing and for which I still have issues

Comment: It's impolite to modify the question after getting an answer. I recommend you to post a "follow up" question.